# Referência System.Configuration

Tags: .net, .net-core, dependências

Estou tentando utilizar a referência do System.Configuration para terminar de integrar as instâncias do meu código com um bloco .txt. Entretanto, notei que diferente dos Visual Studios presentes em videos do youtube, o meu não possui a aba de Referências abaixo da de Dependências no Gerenciador de Soluções.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Portanto, tentei adicionar de outro jeito, clicando em Projeto > Adicionar referência, mas me deparo com a situação de não haver referência alguma para ser adicionada:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não consigo encontrar nada sobre isso na internet. Algum de vocês já passou por isso ou saberia como me ajudar?

Caso não seja esse o intuito do fórum, peço desculpas!

Comment: Botão `direto no projeto> Add Reference > Aba Assemblies> Framework > Procure por System.Configuration`, seria isso?

Comment: Fazendo por este caminho, ele me leva a mesma tela da segunda imagem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu projeto é .NET Core, então você precisa adicionar esta [referência pelo Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CoreCompat.System.Configuration/)

> ```
> PM> Install-Package CoreCompat.System.Configuration -Version 4.2.3-r4 -Pre
> ```

Comment: Linq, a adição da referência ocorreu sem erros. Entretanto, continua do mesmo jeito. É necessário realizar mais alguma ação?

Comment: Não falta o `using` agora?

Comment: Agora foi! Só para eu entender: não é necessário realizar os procedimentos para adicionar manualmente pelo Reference Manager, correto?

Comment: Não é. .NET Core é diferente de .NET Framework.

Answer (score 0):

Só você ir nas Assemblies, e não na sua própria Solution:

No seu projeto, References, Botão direito do mouse, Add Reference:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você poderia me dizer como chego nessa tela?

Comment: atualizado, se for a mesma tela que você estava, não sei o porque não apareceu as opções Assemblies. nos dê mais informações sobre o projeto

Comment: O meu gerenciador de soluções é diferente do seu, repare na primeira imagem que eu anexei ao post. :/

Comment: qual versão do visual studio está utilizando ? qual tipo de projeto está criando ?

Comment: Estou utilizando o Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise, e o tipo de projeto que estou criando é o ConsoleApp.

Comment: Veja a resposta do LINQ